# Raspberry pi Home automation project: issue with web2py

Tags: ssl, raspberry-pi, web2py

I'm trying to do a reaspberry pi project that involves using web2py to create a web interface for the gpio pins, [this](http://www.keytosmart.com/home-automation-with-raspberry-pi/) is the project.

Basically i've got to the point where i try to go to the admin page of web2py, and this should be achieved by accessing the pi's through an ssl connection (through `https://pi_address`), but when i try to do this, all i get is an error in google chrome: Error code: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

It must have something to do with the SSL key that for some reason i'm not getting... i have configured a key using `openssl req -new -key ca.key -out ca.csr` and the files have been generated on the server side (raspberry), but i dont know what to do with them...

I'm pretty sure you need extra info to help me out with this one, but i don't know what else to provide and how to get that info, so if you could please ask for any extra info, i'll be checking this post for the next hours

EDIT:

As asked in an answer, the content of my apache default.conf file:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess web2py user=www-data group=www-data processes=1 threads=1

<VirtualHost *:80>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log common
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/self_signed.cert
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/self_signed.key

  WSGIProcessGroup web2py
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/www-data/web2py/wsgihandler.py
  WSGIPassAuthorization On

  <Directory /home/www-data/web2py>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
    <Files wsgihandler.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  AliasMatch ^/([^/]+)/static/(?:_[\d]+.[\d]+.[\d]+/)?(.*) \
        /home/www-data/web2py/applications/$1/static/$2

  <Directory /home/www-data/web2py/applications/*/static/>
    Options -Indexes
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 hour"
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ssl-access.log common
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the link you provided I'm assuming these two lines are in your apache config:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/self_signed.cert
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/self_signed.key
```

so those are the locations where your generated key files should go. If these lines aren't in your apache config (which should be in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf ) post the contents of that file for further help.

Comment: i forgot the pi at work, i am almost sure they are there, but i will check tomorrow first thing in the morning, thanks :)

Comment: just checked, those lines are there... I just edited the question with the content of my default.conf

Comment: And the .key and .cert files are in those two locations? If so I'm at a loss...is there perhaps a firewall blocking port 443 on the raspberry pi? Other than that best advice I can give is check the Apache error log to see if you can gather anything from there.

Comment: both files are there, I will check for firewalls now